# Angular Disable Container

Tags: html, angular, typescript

Ok, so my question is a commonly asked one but the answers I've discovered so far are unsatisfactory and/or do not exactly answer the scenario I have.

I have created a c# sort of stackpanel component that lays it's contents out vertically or horizontally depending on which one you choose. The html for this is:

```
<div #root
     [fxLayout]="this._orientation"
     fxLayoutAlign="flex-start"
     [fxLayoutGap]="this.spacing"
     [style.marginBottom]="this.margin_bottom"
     [style.marginLeft]="this.margin_left"
     [style.marginRight]="this.margin_right"
     [style.marginTop]="this.margin_top"
     [style.width]="this.width"
     [style.height]="this.height"
     [style.background]="this.background">
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>
```

The fxLayout, fxLayoutAlign, and fxLayoutGap are from the angular flex library and can be npm installed.

So what I'm trying to do is to have another variable

```
@Input() disabled: boolean;
```

in my component file and what I want to do is disable all the children in ng-content. Now let me explain what I DON'T want. I do NOT want a simple style change on the div that turns off click events because the contents can still be tabbed through and you can even press the enter button on the keyboard to press the button or control that's suppose to be disabled.

So what I've got in my head is to get all the children in #root (the div) and set the "disabled" property.

```
private disableChildren(value: boolean) {
  const dom = this.root?.nativeElement?.children;
  if (dom == null) return;
  const list: Element[] = [].slice.call(dom);
  list.filter(x => x['disabled'] != null).forEach(x => x['disabled'] = value);
}
```

The problem with this is that this.root?.nativeElement?.children are HTMLElement and have no references to the component files. Also, some html children have a disabled tag and some don't. For instance 'button' has a disabled tag but a 'mat-icon' doesn't. I've created a bunch of custom components and placed a "disabled" @Input in the component files of all of them (like mat-icon) and I'd like to set that variable from the parent class but I do not see that as possible.

So all that info to ask:

**Is there a way to set a property on a child component inside ng-content? Like from the stackpanel component inside the disable children function set the @Input disabled property?**

OR

**Is there a better way to do this? I honestly don't think there is because I've looked for days on disabling all children in a div and nothing works the way that it should.**

Answer (score 0):

```js
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  this.disableHTMLElement(this.container.nativeElement);
}

private disableHTMLElement(element: HTMLElement): void {
  element.setAttribute('disabled', this.disabled ? 'true' : 'false');

  const children: HTMLElement[] = Array.prototype.slice.call(element.children);
  children.forEach((child) => this.disableHTMLElement(child));
}
```

[Stackblitz demo here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-7ormvx?file=src/app/mycontainer/mycontainer.component.ts)

Comment: Unfortunately this does not disable custom components with their own html. For instance the stackpanel component that I disable has another custom component in it: that component is still able to be interacted with.

Comment: [This stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-7ormvx?file=src/app/app.component.html) provides an example with a custom component, and the input inside it is disabled.

Comment: @PhilipVaughn can you provide an example of it not working?

Comment: I suggest changing the set of disabled attribute by moving into an if container:     if (this.disabled) {
      element.setAttribute('disabled', 'true');
    }